# How to filter certain values in consecutive months?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe structured as follows:

```
Name    Month Grade

Sue     Jan   D

Sue     Feb   D

Jason   Mar   B

Sue     Mar   D

Jason   Jan   B

Sue     Apr   A

Jason   Feb   C
```

I want to get the list of students who got D 3 consecutive months in the past 6 months. In the example above, Sue will be on the list since she got D in Jan, Feb ad March. How can I do that using Python or Pandas or Numpy?

Comment: Are the data sorted temporarily?

Comment: Did you assume that there is the same year?

Comment: @mephisto No. As long as it is consecutive, it can be different years. For example, Jason should be on the list if he got D in November 2018, December 2018 and January 2019.

Comment: is your month exactly as it is here or a proper date? like `Jan 15 2018` or `15/1/2019`

Comment: @ansev What do you mean by temporarily? As far as I know, there is no special sorting about the data.

Comment: @Datanovice Date column is as it is shown here.

Comment: Does the order of input data imply the order of the month? For example, if I have Sue's grade with Jan, Feb,...,Dec in 2018 and Jan, Feb in 2019, does the second Sue Jan always imply the next year?

Comment: @Shenan I am filtering for the last 6 months in the dataset. So there won't be 2 Jan values. However, there might be Nov 18, Dec 18 and Jan 19 values. For example, Jason should be on the list if he gets D in November 2018, December 2018 and January 2019

Comment: @Eenes check solution, this should handle data over multiple years.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your problem. I do have a solution for you but it may not be the fastest in terms of efficiency / code execution. Please see below:

```
newdf = df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Month', values='Grade')
newdf = newdf[['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']].fillna(-1)
newdf['concatenated'] = newdf['Jan'].astype('str') + newdf['Feb'].astype('str') + newdf['Mar'].astype('str') + newdf['Apr'].astype('str')
newdf[newdf['concatenated'].str.contains('DDD', regex=False, na=False)]
```

Output will be like:

```
Month Jan Feb Mar Apr concatenated
Name                              
Sue     D   D   D   A         DDDA
```

If you just want the names, then the following command instead.

```
newdf[newdf['concatenated'].str.contains('DDD', regex=False, na=False)].index.to_list()
```

Comment: Interesting approach, It definitely works and even opens up more interesting insights. The last piece of code didn't work though where you filter the DDD in the concatenated column. Instead, I reset_index and filter the column.

Answer (score 0):

you have a few ways to deal with this, first use my previous solution but this will require mapping academic numbers to months (i.e September = 1, August = 12) that way you can apply math to work out consecutive values.

the following is to covert the Month into a DateTime and work out the difference in months, we can then apply a cumulative sum and filter any values greater than 3.

```
d = StringIO("""Name    Month Grade
Sue     Jan   D
Sue     Feb   D
Jason   Mar   B
Sue     Dec   D 
Jason   Jan   B
Sue     Apr   A
Jason   Feb   C""")

df = pd.read_csv(d,sep='\s+')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'],format='%b').dt.normalize()

# set any values greater than June to the previous year.
df['date'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.month > 6,
 (df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1)),df['date']) 

df.sort_values(['Name','date'],inplace=True)

def month_diff(date):
    cumlative_months = (
        np.round(((date.sub(date.shift(1)) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")))).eq(1).cumsum() 
    ) + 1
return cumlative_months

df['count'] = df.groupby(["Name", "Grade"])["date"].apply(month_diff)
```

---

```
print(df.drop('date',axis=1))
    Name Month Grade  count
4  Jason   Jan     B      1
6  Jason   Feb     C      1
2  Jason   Mar     B      1
3    Sue   Dec     D      1
0    Sue   Jan     D      2
1    Sue   Feb     D      3
5    Sue   Apr     A      1
```

---

```
print(df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Sue'])
  Name Month Grade      date   count
3  Sue   Dec     D 1899-12-01      1
0  Sue   Jan     D 1900-01-01      2
1  Sue   Feb     D 1900-02-01      3
5  Sue   Apr     A 1900-04-01      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this.

```
df['Month_Nr'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format='%b').dt.month

names  = df.Name.unique()
students = np.array([])

for name in names:
    filter = df[(df.Name==name) & (df.Grade=='D')].sort_values('Month_Nr')
    if filter['Month_Nr'].diff().cumsum().max() >= 2:
        students = np.append(students, name)

print(students)
```

Output:

```
['Sue']
```